# Populate High value PostgreSQL timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I'm using the PostgreSQL timestamp to determine the end date of a row and would like to populate high values such as "9999-12-31 00.00.00.000000".

How can I do that using a query?

Comment: There is no max value for date type in psql -  in theory it's limited by number of bytes for particular type and value it can store. Check [date/time types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-datetime.html) page or show any other effort you have done for solving actual problem before posting a question. `infinity` value is what you might be looking for

Comment: Sentinel values are generally a bad idea. Can you be a little more specific about what you're doing? There's almost certainly a better way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

The greatest possible value for a timestamp in PostgreSQL is the special value `infinity` (`+infinity` or positive infinity).

The greatest non-infinite value depends on the date/time representation and the data types on the platform. That's part of why it's often best to use `infinity` or if more appropriate, `null`.

If you use `infinity`, note that many programming languages don't define an infinite value for their date/time types. So the database driver must pick a sentinel value on the client language side to represent infinity. Then it has the problem that it doesn't know, when writing data back to the server, if the client application meant that value or its use as a placeholder for infinity. So even though `infinity` is the *correct* choice when you want a "higher than everything" value, it's not necessarily a *practical* choice.

If you really must have a high sentinel value, choose one that's the lowest common maximum among all the client applications and languages you want to use, for both their timestamp and date types. Then add a `check` constraint that prevents any higher values from being inserted.